# 127.0.0.1:3000ではページが表示されるが、localhost:3000 で表示されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

現在、VSCode にて開発環境を作成し、`rails s` でサーバーを立ち上げましたが、
`http://localhost:3000/` でページが表示されず画像のような状態になります。

調べたところ `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` では開ける記事がありましたので、試したところ、立ち上がりました。
これは何故でしょうか？また、`http://127.0.0.1:3000/` で開発を進めても宜しいでしょうか？
お手数おかけしますが、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

補足：バージョンは、ruby 2.7.1p83、Rails 5.2.4.3です。
宜しくお願い致します。

`http://127.0.0.1:3000/` の画面:
[image: http://127.0.0.1:3000/]

`http://localhost:3000/` の画面:
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご回答頂き、ありがとうございます。OSはMacを使用しているので、添付してくださった資料を拝見させて頂きたいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

使っているOSはWindows, Mac, Linuxのどれになりますでしょうか。

127.0.0.1 はループバックアドレスという特別な値で、「そのコンピューター自身」を指します。
localhost は通例的に 127.0.0.1 を指すのですが、hostsという特別なファイルに定義をしてあげないと動かないことがあります。

Windows: https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/972034/how-to-reset-the-hosts-file-back-to-the-default

macOS: https://uiuifree.com/blog/develop/mac-hosts/

Linux: https://linuc.org/study/knowledge/506/

この辺を参考になさってください。